# Persist Data from a Domain Object on a Timer / Event?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working through an example coding challenge with the goal of understanding DDD and vertical slice architecture.  In short, I am building a .NET 8 WebAPI to manage movies, theaters, showings, and seat  reservation.

I am persisting the domain objects to a database via EF Core. This persistence logic and the domain object are completely separate.

When a seat is "Reserved", it goes into a pending state.  The only way it gets out of this state is either:

1. `Confirm()` or
2. The `OccupancyStateExpiration` time has passed.

I would like to have the seat move from Reserved to Vacant after the time has passed auto-magically - AND have this persisted to the database.

I know to avoid adding database logic within the domain object, but how would one approach this correctly, keeping in mind DDD?

The object of conversation:

```
namespace CinemaBooking.Theaters.Domain;

public class Seat
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; }
    public OccupancyState Occupancy { get; set; } = OccupancyState.Vacant;
    public DateTime? OccupancyStateExpiration { get; set; } = null;
    public required string Row { get; set; }
    public required ushort Number { get; set; }

    public Result Reserve(ushort pendingTimeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (Occupancy != OccupancyState.Vacant) return SeatError.InvalidAction;

        Occupancy = OccupancyState.Pending;
        OccupancyStateExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(pendingTimeoutInSeconds);

        return Result.Success();
    }
    public Result Release()
    {
        Occupancy = OccupancyState.Vacant;
        OccupancyStateExpiration = null;
        return Result.Success();
    }
    public Result Confirm()
    {
        if (Occupancy != OccupancyState.Pending) return SeatError.InvalidAction;

        Occupancy = OccupancyState.Reserved;
        OccupancyStateExpiration = null;

        return Result.Success();
    }

    public enum OccupancyState
    {
        Vacant = 1,
        Pending = 2,
        Reserved = 3
    }

    public enum OccupancyAction
    {
        Reserve = 1,
        Release = 2,
        Confirm = 3
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly where to go from here, as it's more of an architectural question as opposed to a mechanical one.  I believe using an event *in* the domain object that gets fired after the timeout makes sense, however, assuming the database state is "king" - it may be a completely separate thing that simply monitors the DB?

In some reading, I believe I'm on the verge of "Domain Events"?

Comment: Well in most DBs you can have a ServerAgent (fancy name for a regular executing task), which checks every lets say 5 mins or every day if the Time has expired, and then do something with it. Is the expiration based on the day or an exact hour?

Comment: It's meant to be X seconds after the seat was moved from Vacant to Pending.  So any seat can expire at any time.  That's why it feels like it needs to be event driven.  Your thought above is interesting, but it's potentially not something that can be scheduled.

Comment: Have you has a look at System.Timers.Time? This seems like just what you need

Comment: _" That's why it feels like it needs to be event driven"_ - why? All you need is an expirationTimestamp instead of changing a _state_ at exactly the right time.

Comment: ^^ Of course, if you are using something like Redis, you could also set a TTL. Which boils ddown to the same concept, basically.

Comment: The problem of timed events is always: What if the trigger is delayed? What if the trigger isn't fired at all? What's the behavior regarding daylight savings change? - In my book it's always easier to say "you are reserved until 2024-02-16T14:15:00Z" and include a current datetime-based filter in the Get-Query. -- Or as I said in case of Redis "Add Reservation with TTL of 2 hours" ... But I am not a DDD guy, so that may not apply there.

Comment: @Fildor If I read you correctly, "Pending" automatically has business logic as part of it's definition, so I'd need to run / check validate that logic every time I look at the object, right?

Comment: Depends. But I guess so. But it's not really different. It's instead of checking `pending == Pending.Reserved` or something like that you check a timestamp for null or greater (or less, depending on how you implement it) ... roughly said. I haven't thought through all the details and corner cases, but that's roughly it.

Answer (score 0):

Now you will need too make some changes to make this fit better with your requirements, but here is something as a basic template/idea

```cs
public class Seat
{
    //your code
    private Timer? ExpirationTimer;
    
    public Result Reserve(ushort pendingTimeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (Occupancy != OccupancyState.Vacant) return SeatError.InvalidAction;

        Occupancy = OccupancyState.Pending;
        OccupancyStateExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(pendingTimeoutInSeconds);
        ExpirationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer()
        {
            AutoReset = false,
            Interval = pendingTimeoutInSeconds * 1000
        };

        ExpirationTimer.Elapsed += ElapsedEvent;

        ExpirationTimer.Start();

        return Result.Success();
    }
    
    public void ElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExpirationTimer.Stop();
        ExpirationTimer.Elapsed -= ElapsedEvent;
        ExpirationTimer = null;
        //do what you need to do 
    }

    
}
```

Comment: There defenetly are better ways then to create it everytime in the Reserve method, but this is just to get the general idea across

Comment: I'm not a DDD expert, and although this helps me understand events better, I would not want to add database persistence to the `ElapsedEvent` method here, right?  Then the domain object is incorrectly tied to the database.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean by adding the Event to the db persistence.
Also I need too mention that I am not all that experienced with DDD myself

Comment: Why would you use an _event_ when you can just save a timestamp and compare it to "now"?

Comment: @Fildor because as I understand it this is supposed to run automatically. At least thats what they requested.

Comment: But this is just a base. I do agree that they should not do it like this exactly. But since I dont know the outside code this is all I can give.

Comment: A timestamp _does expire automatically_. In that it is in the past or in the future ... just without actually _executing_ anything. With the pro that you can easily have eventual consistency, should anything happen. An event not raised (on time) will always be an event not raised (on time).

Comment: @Fildor buts its supposed to execute something. Once the expiration hits they want the Status changed and a call to the DB to be made.

Comment: _"its supposed to execute something"_ - is it, though? You can have the exact semantics without the eventing. And safer.

Comment: @Fildor  fair point. As I understand it they wanted something to happen once the Time expires. But this is most defenetly not my perfered way to do it. Id sau a look at the outside classes/their interface, would be very helpfull.